# How to get a pillow "squashy" again after a few years of usage?

Tags: bedroom

My pillows were bought a few years ago. At that time, they were squashy & bouncy.

Now, they are flat with no bounciness; I need to stack up two of them to get them to the same height.

Comment: What material / filling are we talking about?

Comment: Pillows wear out. Yours are now old and worn out. Buy new ones.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While time period varies by material, by any definition pillows you bought "a few years ago" are old, and you aren't going to lifehack them back to new. Regular polyester pillows last about two years, after which they get flat like you're describing. The fibers are matted and compressed, it's full of skin and sweat, and it's time to toss it and buy a new pillow.

You can see a full chart of how frequently to replace your pillow [here at tuck.com](https://www.tuck.com/how-often-should-you-replace-pillows/#when_should_you_replace_your_pillow_); note that the longest specified lifespan is for latex (not a "squashy and bouncy" filling) at 4 years.

Answer (score 1):

I have revitalized pillows by putting them in a drier with something hard like a shoe, and running it on no heat.

Answer (score 0):

You won't. Best thing to do is wash them with detergent in a front loader washer and then dry them in a dryer on medium heat. This will also help get out mites and oils which matt the fibers.

Comment: Why a front loader washer? My top loader washing machine can do everything a front loader can.